# "Failed to start" notifications when booting into Ubuntu

Tags: boot, firewall, support

When attempting to boot I get the following messages:

```
Failed to start Set the console keyboard layout
```

And

```
Failed to start Uncomplicated firewall
```

The screen has remained the same for about 30 minutes and has not continued to boot.

Comment: When did this start? Anything you did that might be relared? Oh and those are not errors but notifications. Errors during boot must have "err" or "crit" on the line during boot. Both of these can be fixed on command line and are likely not the reason for a crash. 1 thing to test: does control-alt-f3 switch to console mode?  If so you can examine the system from there See /var/log/ and the files there for notices. Can also be done from a live session. Failure to boot tends to be graphics driver related.  Edit the Q please. Ill remove this when you have

Comment: 1st one will be fixed with: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`  or `sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup` if you correctly answer the questions it asks. 2nd one: `sudo ufw reload && sudo service ufw restart` will fix the 2nd. Both need a terminal session though ;)

Comment: control-alt-f3 doesn't seem to open console mode